# IDistributedCache call a constructor with injection

Tags: c#, caching, redis

I have a project using `redis` distributed cache based on asp.net core 2.1 solution. There's something that I haven't understood.

I have a class `myClassName` with a constructor subject to injection.

```
public class myClassName
{
   private readonly IDistributedCache _userCache;

   public  myClassName(IDistributedCache distributedCache) => _userCache
    = distributedCache;

   public async Task FirstMethod(...)

   private async Task SecondMethod(...)

}
```

from another class "myClassNameTwo" I have to create a "myClassName" instance and access to some methods.

So I have :

```
   Public class myClassNameTwo : Hub
   {
      private readonly AssetsBroadcaster _broadcaster;

      public myClassNameTwo(AssetsBroadcaster broadcaster)
      {
        _broadcaster = broadcaster;           
      }

      public async Task DoSomething(...) 
      {
        myClassName hello = new myClassName(???)

        await hello.FirstMethod(...)
      }
  }
```

How can retrieve the `IDistributedCache` service instance to pass to `myClassName` constructor?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. ;) Feel free to read [ask] and check out the [tour] for a better view of the site. ;) ;) ;)

Comment: Please be careful with tags, this is not C but C# -> fixed

Comment: Ok sorry ;) thanks !

Comment: Why dont you inject instants of myClassName into the myClassNameTwo?

Comment: Are you using .net core?

Comment: @AkbarBadhusha the second class is a signalR hub.  Yes it's net core 2.1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net Core, Using dependency injunction, You can inject the instants of the myClassName class if you have registered it in the startup.

like,

```
public class myClassName{

private readonly IDistributedCache _userCache;

public  myClassName(IDistributedCache distributedCache) {
 _userCache = distributedCache;
}

public async Task FirstMethod(...)

private async Task SecondMethod(...)

}
```

For the second class  it can be like following

```
   Public class myClassNameTwo : Hub
   {
      private readonly AssetsBroadcaster _broadcaster;
      private readonly myClassName _myClassName;

      public myClassNameTwo(AssetsBroadcaster broadcaster,
                myClassName myClassName)
      {
        _broadcaster = broadcaster;     
        _myClassName = myClassName;   
      }

      public async Task DoSomething(...) 
      {    
        await _myClassName.FirstMethod(...)
      }
  }
```

Dependencies for the myClassName will be automatically injected. So you don't need to inject it separately.

[For more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection)

Comment: in order to provide a better view : the second class can't have a constructor with IDistributedCache injection because is a SignalR Hub.

Comment: myClassNameTwo does not need to have IDistributedCache injected. It just need myClassName

Comment: I edited the code posted, now should be more detailed ;)

Comment: I have updated the answer, Hope it make sense. Or is there any other reason you want to send the distributed cache instance to the myClassName? Let me know @MassimoMannoni

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately doesn't works. An exception is catcher when the SignalR Hub is called by JS.  ==>  Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error.'. This happen because when the JS client call the HUB and the constructor is called , the second parameter isn't passed ... well.. basically I don't think that incapsulate the class in another can solve the question ;) I don't understand if, when a service has been created in ConfigureService, it can be reach only thought injection or there are other ways ....

Comment: can you share how you call it from js?

Comment: let  myClassNameTwo = new signalR.HubConnection("http://localhost:1784/PushEngine");

 myClassNameTwo.start().then(function () {

    console.log('Push Engine On');

});     myClassNameTwo.invoke("DoSomething", parameters);

Comment: I've tried to use the methods indicated on microsoft document by the way use an interface don't allow you to do not performe the injection. In any case you'll pass to the constructor that required the injection of IdistributedCache ...